# PHP Replicated Database Sessions Failover

Tags: php, mysql, session, failover, high-availability

I have 2 servers available for failover.  The database is replicated (MySQL) as a Master-Master, such that, each server runs a copy of the full-stack.  I see the session table get updated when I'm on one server, and after inspecting the requests, I see the same PHPSESSID being sent.  But, when I change URLs or failover to the secondary machine, my session is killed and I have to re-login.

Same PHPSESSID value is sent on the secondary, but the session is not recognized.  Is Apache/PHP linking the session to that particular box?  If so, how can I get them to recognize the session that is already in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Moved from 'EDIT' to an answer to mark as answered

Actually found the solution. The 'problem' is the Suhosin patch for securing the PHP installation. Suhosin supports configurable options for encrypting the session data based on a crypt key, as well as the DocRoot of the application, since the failover server had a different DocRoot, there was no chance of the encrypted data being read.

I edited suhosin.ini to add a shared crypt key, and turned off the DocRoot encryption option, and the sessions are shared as expected.

Solution via: http://rommelsantor.com/clog/2011/02/06/php-shared-session-encoding-solution/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `$_SESSION` then that is tied down to that server. You should use a cookie to track session ids and then match it back up with a session in the DB.

Comment: @drowe: Review this PHP function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: I am using $_SESSION, and I have the cookie value in PHPSESSID which matches the ID in the database.  But, when PHP attempts to use the session data, it borks.  What part of it is tied to the specific server though?  And can I override it, such that one server recognizes the session data from the other?

Comment: You should read up on how sessions work. Sessions in PHP operate by giving the clients a token via a cookie, and then storing the data in $_SESSION locally on the disk. When the client connects again it will reunite the session token with the data stored on disk.

Comment: @JohnD - The session data is not stored on disk, but rather in the database, which is replicated.  The token in the cookie is being passed correctly between the primary and secondary servers - and the secondary is reading the session data correctly out of the database, but then (I believe) PHP sees it as invalid, and clears it.

Comment: PHP's $_SESSION stores on the disk.

Comment: Are you trolling?  If using the database to store session data, and registering the methods for doing so using session_set_save_handler, how do you figure the session data is stored on disk, which I presume you mean in text files?  I believe _you_ need to read up on how sessions work.

Comment: "registering the methods for doing so using session_set_save_handler" You never mentioned that anywhere until now.

Comment: How else did you think I was storing the session data in the database?

Comment: Using a separate system like most web applications?